# Android seekbar easy way to display the progress when onProgressChanged is triggered

Tags: android, android-seekbar

Is there any easy way to show some kind of flag or Toast-like (not a Toast..) indication when the user is dragging the seekbar? I've implemented OnSeekBarChangeListener like this

```
@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    int position = seekBar.getProgress();
    service.seekToPosition(position);
}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
        boolean fromUser) {
    if(fromUser){

    }
}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

it gets the seek bar progress after the user has stopped the drag movement and sets the current music playback to that position.

In the onProgressChanged method i'd like to display the seekbar progress while the user is dragging the seekbar.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Marcus

Comment: you can use custom dialog on the seekbar and display the progress onprogresschanged and remove that dialog onStopTrackingTouch.

Comment: How do you mean 'on the seekbar'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just create a framelayout or relativelayout. Put a textview in front of your view and make the background black, maybe a bit see through and the textcolor white. Set visibility to false. When onProgressChanged is called make it visible and update the textview accordingly to the seekbar. When you release the seekbar set visibility to false again.